# Bootstrap Dropdown: add class when re-rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap's `.dropdown.show .dropdown-menu` changes its position `top / bottom` and `bottom / top` upon scrolling to always be in view.

How, whenever it happens, can I add a class `rendered-on-top` / `rendered-on-bottom` to the `.dropdown` parent?

I have noticed, that it adds `x-placement` attribute to the `.dropdown-menu` element whenever re-rendered.

Something like:

```
$('.dropdown').on('render', function(ev) {

    $(this).addClass(ev.direction);

});
```

Where `ev.direction` would be where it appeared in relation to its `.dropdown-toggle`.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6ap6xmpk/)

[image]

Comment: can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: A fiddle of what, bootstrap dropdown?

Comment: Disregard. I just realized that's from the bootstrap website.

Comment: I added it anyway.

Comment: What exactly do you need this additional class for? // Depending on when BS sets this `x-placement` attribute, perhaps you could read its content in `show.bs.dropdown` or `shown.bs.dropdown` events?

Comment: I could not, tried both. I need it to style the `.dropdown-toggle::after { content: ''; }` based on the position. I know that I can swap `.dropdown-toggle` with `.dropdown-menu` in HTML and the do it with `[x-position='direction'] + .dropdown-toggle::after` css selector, but it is not the "standard" way of adding `.dropdown` HTML, so I'd rather add little JS than change what ppl are used to.

Comment: Any reason you can't use z-index??

Comment: I don't think I follow you, `z-index`? For what?

Comment: you could do something like $(".dropdown").on("change", function(){if($(this).hasAttr('x-placement') // do stuff)})

Comment: Is your issue that you want the the content below the dropdown to appear on top of the dropdown?

Comment: or is that not the purpose of a class called rendered-on-top ?

Comment: It is not the purpose of the class name; `rendered-on-top` as per *rendered on top of the `.dropdown-toggle`* .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `x-placement` attribute of the `dropdown menu` to add or remove class on scroll. I have made a function **addYourClass()** which you can fire at on **scroll** or on **click** event

You can see the changing `background-color` effect when scrolling in below snippet.

***Stack Snippet***

```js
$(document).on('scroll click', function() {
  addYourClass($(".dropdown"));
});
$(document).on('click','.dropdown .btn', function() {
  addYourClass($(".dropdown"));
});

function addYourClass($item) {
  if ($('.dropdown-menu.show').length) {
    if ($item.find(".dropdown-menu").attr("x-placement") == "bottom-start") {
      $item.addClass("rendered-on-bottom").removeClass("rendered-on-top");
    } else if ($item.find(".dropdown-menu").attr("x-placement") == "top-start") {
      $item.addClass("rendered-on-top").removeClass("rendered-on-bottom");
    }
  } else {
    $item.removeClass("rendered-on-top rendered-on-bottom");
  }
}
```

```css
.dropdown {
  margin: 200px 150px 0;
}

body {
  height: 600px;
}

.dropdown.rendered-on-top .btn {
  background: red !important;
}

.dropdown.rendered-on-bottom .btn {
  background: blue !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I thought of it before, but I'd rather rely on `.on()` and `.trigger()` than `scroll` event, unrelated to the `.dropdown` itself. But thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".dropdown").on("shown.bs.dropdown",function(){
  var ele = $(this).find(".dropdown-menu");
  $(document).on("scroll",ddonchange(ele));
});
function ddonchange(ele){
    if($(ele).attr("x-placement")=='bottom-start')
        $(ele).parent().addClass("myclass");
}
```